# @Singleton vs @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)

Tags: android, singleton, dagger-hilt

What's the difference between these two? I think they both annotate a singleton object/instance, but somehow `@Singleton` can be used to annotate methods, instead of classes. I'm really confused about both of them.

Answer (score 1):

@SingletonComponent specifies that it can be used in the entire application.

@Singleton is a software design pattern causes the object to be initialized once.

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationComponent` being renamed to `SingletonComponent`, to allow usage of Hilt in non-Android Gradle modules [link](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.28.2)

but `@Singleton` is a  software design pattern [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: Cool, I was thinking about `ApplicationComponent` too, but I thought it wasn't relevant so I didn't ask about it.

Comment: Then are `@Singleton` and `@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)` effectively the same? Because there can be only 1 `SingletonComponent`/`ApplicationComponent` (I think so).

Comment: @MinhNghĩa actually no. they are not same.

Comment: I mean they're *effectively* the same, as there's only 1 instance of the class annotated with either annotation. Or I'm I missing something? For example, if the constraint of a single instance `@Singleton` only applies to 1 "container", then there can be `n` instances across `n` different containers, and in that case, I'm definitely wrong.

Comment: @MinhNghĩa the `@Singleton` used in dagger is `singleton double check pattern`  and in the app you just have a instance, but multithreading can cause the have `n` instance without `@Singleton`

Comment: I also want to know the answer to this question. When our app module is already singleton then why annotate its methods with a singleton?

Comment: The answer doesn't really explain what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Instances of components provided in the modules specified as
`@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)` live throughout the application lifecycle.So, it refers component's lifetime.

While using injections(such as field or constructor), Hilt provides the instance of the components. If we want these components also created only once, we should add the `@Singleton` scope annotation. If we do not add this, a new instances are constantly created.

However scoping a binding to a component can be costly because the provided object stays in memory until that component is destroyed. That's why by default, all bindings in Hilt are unscoped, you need to use them according to your needs. You can read the [details](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#component-scopes) in Android official website.

Comment: I have some binds or provides relations for ActivityComponent and some for SingletonComponent in one Hilt Module class .... how could i achieve that?